# Rename specific files depending on a diferent file in same directory

Tags: ruby

I'm practising some programming and I'm now faced with the following issue. I have a folder with multiple subfolders inside. Each subfolder contains two files: an `.xlsx` and a `.doc` file. I want to rename the `.xlsx` depending on the name of the `.doc` file. For example, in directory `documents\main_folder\folder_1` there are two files: `test_file.xlsx` and `final_file.doc`. After running my code, result should be `final_file.xlsx` and `final_file.doc`. This must happen with all subfolders.

My code so far:

```
    require 'FileUtils'

    filename = nil
    files = Dir.glob('**/*.doc')
    files.each do |rename|
    filename = File.basename(rename, File.extname(rename))
    puts "working with file: #{filename}"
    end

    subs = Dir.glob('**/*.xlsx')
    subs.each do |renaming|
    File.rename(renaming, filename)
    end
```

Two issues with this code: firstly, the `.xlsx` is moved where the `.rb` file is located. Secondly, renaming is partially achieved, only that the extension is not kept, but completely removed. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dir.glob('**/*.doc').each do |doc_file|
  # extract folder path e.g. "./foo" from "./foo/bar.doc"
  dir = File.dirname(doc_file) 

  # extract filename without extension e.g. "bar" from "./foo/bar.doc"
  basename = File.basename(doc_file, File.extname(doc_file)) 

  # find the xlsx file in the same folder
  xlsx_file = Dir.glob("#{dir}/*.xlsx")[0]

  # perform the replacement
  File.rename(xlsx_file, "#{dir}/#{basename}.xlsx")
end
```

*edit*

the validation step you requested:

```
# first, get all the directories
dirs = Dir.glob("**/*").select { |path| File.directory?(path) }

# then validate each of them
dirs.each do |dir|
  [".doc", ".xlxs"].each do |ext|
    # raise an error unless the extension has exactly 1 file
    unless Dir.glob("#{dir}/*#{ext}").count == 1
      raise "#{dir} doesn't have exactly 1 #{ext} file"
    end
  end
end
```

You can also bunch up the errors into one combined message if you prefer ... just push the error message into an `errors` array instead of raising them as soon as they come up

Comment: Wow! This works fantastically well! I will study the code in depth. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One more question: I finally want to validate that in each subfolder, there is one `.xlsx` file and a `.doc` file, just one for each. Any suggestions where to start?

Comment: Thank you, Max. I did a test by deleting one file of the subfolders on purpuse and I got a RuntimeError, because the parent directory (the one containing all subfolders) doesn't have any of two files. Is there any way I could skip the parent folder and just validate the subfolders?

Comment: I think that's just an issue with the Dir.glob, just try `parent/*`  (you don't need the `**/*` if you're not going multiple levels deep). Mess around with that a bit I think you can figure it out.